# Aspx page load js syntax

Tags: javascript, html

please if you help me to check the spell i realy apreciate
is not passing thru
regards

```html
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if ($(<%=Session("acepto")%>).val() === 0) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
</script>
```

the script passing thru, i think is misspelled

Comment: Im trying to open a modal window only if the value=0

Comment: You can't mix server side code with Javascript like that

Comment: [How can I debug my JavaScript code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/988363/how-can-i-debug-my-javascript-code)

Comment: What's in your `acepto` session variable?

Comment: in the session variable its a 0

Comment: A zero? What is `$(0).val()` supposed to do? O.o

Comment: Show the modal!

Comment: [jQuery Learning Center](https://learn.jquery.com)

Comment: Please see: [How do I avoid misusing tags?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354427/how-do-i-avoid-misusing-tags)

Comment: @ErnestoDeObaldía the point is that `$(0).val()` is meaningless.

Comment: ok let me prove!

Comment: Change it and still not working!

Comment: You changed it and it's still not working?  Maybe if you share what you changed....

Comment: <script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).on('load', function () {
        if ($(<%=Session("acepto")%>).$($0).val  {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
</script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var name = '<%= Session("acepto") %>';
        $(window).on('load', function () {
    if (name==0 )  {
        $('#myModal').modal('show');
    }
});
```